# Can't connect to Node.js/Jest inspector on exposed Docker container port

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs

Can't connect to Jest inspector (port 9230) on Node.js Chrome inspector

When I run: 
`docker exec -it test_api_run_eb9ed32c928a wget -qO- http://localhost:9230/json`

JSON is returned from container:

```
[ {
  "description": "node.js instance",
  "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9230/a0dab38a-e6d8-43a3-a459-e3ea9eabf470",
  "devtoolsFrontendUrlCompat": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9230/a0dab38a-e6d8-43a3-a459-e3ea9eabf470",
  "faviconUrl": "https://nodejs.org/static/favicon.ico",
  "id": "a0dab38a-e6d8-43a3-a459-e3ea9eabf470",
  "title": "node_modules/.bin/jest",
  "type": "node",
  "url": "file:///usr/src/sand/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
  "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9230/a0dab38a-e6d8-43a3-a459-e3ea9eabf470"
} ]
```

- But when I access `chrome://inspect` the resource isn't listed. I have already added `localhost:9230` as a network target for discovery.
- When I access `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/js_app.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9230/a0dab38a-e6d8-43a3-a459-e3ea9eabf470` in browser, Chrome errors with:
- `Debugging connection was closed. Reason: WebSocket disconnected`

**Docker Port**

Running `docker port test_api_run_eb9ed32c928a 9230` returns:
`Error: No public port '9230/tcp' published for test_api_run_eb9ed32c928a`

**Docker Compose Snippet:**

```
    expose:
      - '8000'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9230:9230'
```

- I've tried removing `127.0.0.1:` from `ports:` on this compose as well

**Node.js / Jest start command:**

`node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9230 node_modules/.bin/jest --forceExit --runInBand`

CLI output:
`Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9230/74d22b62-051d-4aa3-b312-5f4defb170e6`

Running `netstat -a` in container:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9230            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:41339        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
netstat: /proc/net/tcp6: No such file or directory
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:53289        0.0.0.0:*
netstat: /proc/net/udp6: No such file or directory
netstat: /proc/net/raw6: No such file or directory
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
```

**Docker inspect on container (NetworkSettings snippet):**

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "5c1fb6ad8189e4407cf40eb8dc0d9f0f8eacc13df6bb0b45b8d48d51da33655f",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "9230/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/5c1fb6ad8189",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "test_sand": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "51117364a172"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "338c689e41c4ecbb691626560f6f98a04f6d9a93e640a766d37faa773e5ce760",
                    "EndpointID": "0c161fd96b88a60ea10a85d81aeda09cd936added4363dd7ba6613dea3ad9045",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

The area that looks problematic is:

```
"Ports": {
    "9230/tcp": null
},
```

- Netstat output also looks odd

Is there a step I'm missing to resolve, or is there a port misconfiguration, or something else interfering with the network?

Comment: Can you include a little more context around the `docker-compose.yml` snippet?  That's also the section that looks problematic to me, and it would generally imply you have the port exposed but not published (the `ports:` declaration isn't applying).

Comment: @DavidMaze : I've added the full docker compose now, thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze fixed it now with include of `--service-ports` on docker-compose run

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by including `--service-ports` on docker-compose run